# Find rows with multiple duplicate fields with Active Record, Rails & Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

What is the best way to find records with duplicate values across multiple columns using Postgres, and Activerecord?

I found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4564716/2229277):

`User.find(:all, :group => [:first, :email], :having => "count(*) > 1" )`

But it doesn't seem to work with postgres. I'm getting this error:

PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "parts.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: In regular SQL, I'd use a self-join, something like `select a.id, b.id, name, email FROM user a INNER JOIN user b USING (name, email) WHERE a.id > b.id`. No idea how to express that in ActiveRecord-speak.

Answer (score 287, accepted):

**Tested & Working Version**

```
User.select(:first,:email).group(:first,:email).having("count(*) > 1")
```

Also, this is a little unrelated but handy. If you want to see how times each combination was found, put .size at the end:

```
User.select(:first,:email).group(:first,:email).having("count(*) > 1").size
```

and you'll get a result set back that looks like this:

```
{[nil, nil]=>512,
 ["Joe", "test@test.com"]=>23,
 ["Jim", "email2@gmail.com"]=>36,
 ["John", "email3@gmail.com"]=>21}
```

Thought that was pretty cool and hadn't seen it before.

Credit to Taryn, this is just a tweaked version of her answer.

Comment: I had to  pass an explict array to `select()` as in: `User.select([:first,:email]).group(:first,:email).having("count(*) > 1").count` in order to work.

Comment: adding the `.count` gives `PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function count`

Comment: You can try User.select([:first,:email]).group(:first,:email).having("count(*) > 1").map.count

Comment: I'm trying the same method but trying to get the User.id as well, adding it to the select and group returns an empty array.  How can I return the whole User model, or at least include the :id?

Comment: Try doing something like `User.select('count(email) as email_total, first, email').group(:first,:email)` and then `email_total` for its count.

Comment: use `.size`instead of `.count`

Comment: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "users.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: Thanks for this answer ! I need to make a scope out of this request (with all the duplicates). I have written `User.select(:first,:email).group(:first,:email).having("count(*) > 1").inject(User.none) {|scope, u| scope.or(User.where(first: u.first, email: u.email)) }`. Is there any simpler way ?

Comment: How do you make a case insensitive duplicate search?

Comment: This is what worked for me in Postgres: `User.select([:first,:email]).group(:first,:email).having("count(*) > 1").map.size`

Answer (score 44):

That error occurs because POSTGRES requires you to put grouping columns in the SELECT clause.

try:

```
User.select(:first,:email).group(:first,:email).having("count(*) > 1").all
```

(note: not tested, you may need to tweak it)

EDITED to remove id column

Comment: That's not going to work; the `id` column is not part of the group, so you cannot refer it unless you aggregate it (e.g. `array_agg(id)` or `json_agg(id)`)

Answer (score 19):

If you need the full models, try the following (based on @newUserNameHere's answer).

```
User.where(email: User.select(:email).group(:email).having("count(*) > 1").select(:email))
```

This will return the rows where the email address of the row is not unique.

I'm not aware of a way to do this over multiple attributes.

Comment: ```
User.where(email: User.select(:email).group(:email).having("count(*) > 1"))
```

Comment: Thank you that works great :)
Also seems like it the last `.select(:email)` is redundant.

I think this is a little cleaner, but I could be wrong. 
`User.where(email: User.select(:email).group(:email).having("count(*) > 1"))`

Comment: perfect! this solution finds ActiveRecord instances. just what I was looking for

Answer (score 8):

Get all duplicates with a **single query** if you use **PostgreSQL**:

```
def duplicated_users
  duplicated_ids = User
    .group(:first, :email)
    .having("COUNT(*) > 1")
    .select('unnest((array_agg("id"))[2:])')

  User.where(id: duplicated_ids)
end

irb> duplicated_users
```

Answer (score 2):

I struggled to get proper `User` models returned via the accepted answer. Here's how:

```rb
User
  .group(:first, :email)
  .having("COUNT(*) > 1")
  .select('array_agg("id") as ids')
  .map(&:ids)
  .map { |group| group.map { |id| User.find(id) } }
```

This will return proper models you can interact with as:

```
[
  [User#1, User#2],
  [User#35, User#59],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Works well in raw SQL:

```sql
# select array_agg(id) from attendances group by event_id, user_id having count(*) > 1;
   array_agg   
---------------
 {3712,3711}
 {8762,8763}
 {7421,7420}
 {13478,13477}
 {15494,15493}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @itsnikolay 's [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52968653/318699) but making a method that you can pass any ActiveRecord scope to

```
#pass in a scope, and list of columns to group by
# map(&:dupe_ids) to see your list 
def duplicate_row_ids(ar_scope, attrs)
  ar_scope
    .group(attrs)
    .having("COUNT(*) > 1")
    .select('array_agg("id") as dupe_ids')      
end

 #initial scope to narrow where you want to look for dupes
 ar_scope = ProductReviews.where( product_id: "194e676b-741e-4143-a0ce-10cf268290bb", status: "Rejected")
#pass the scope, and list of columns to group by
results = duplicate_row_ids(ar_scope, [:nickname, :overall_rating, :source, :product_id, :headline, :status])
#get your list
id_pairs = results.map &:dupe_ids
#each entry is an array
#then go through your pairs and take action
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21769544/2667984) by @newUserNameHere I believe the right way to show the count for each is

```rb
res = User.select('first, email, count(1)').group(:first,:email).having('count(1) > 1')

res.each {|r| puts r.attributes } ; nil
```