# How to check if for one record two fields have same value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I am trying to check if two fields have same value for one record in mongodb through rails. I want to check if the value in actual_user_id and user_id are same.

```
JobPosting.where(:actual_user_id => :user_id, created_at: @yesterday.midnight..@yesterday.end_of_day).count
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to return all values with a duplicate actual_user_id and user_id? If that's the case:

```
JobPosting.select(:actual_user_id,:user_id).group(:actual_user_id,:user_id).having("count(*) > 1")
```

If you want to find how many duplicates there are, try adding size on the end:

```
JobPosting.select(:actual_user_id,:user_id).group(:actual_user_id,:user_id).having("count(*) > 1").size
```

If however you know the user_id and actual_user_id you want to search for, and have assigned them to variables:

```
JobPosting.where(actual_user_id: actual_user_id, user_id: user_id)
```

The first will return groups of duplicates, the second will return the duplicate values with how often they appear, and the final will return all records with an actual_user_id and user_id matching the given values.

Taken from: [Find rows with multiple duplicate fields with Active Record, Rails & Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21669202/find-rows-with-multiple-duplicate-fields-with-active-record-rails-postgres)

EDIT:
To include the created_at in the query and get the number of duplicates along with the values, I think you're looking at:

```
JobPosting
  .where(created_at: @yesterday.midnight..@yesterday.end_of_day)
  .select(:actual_user_id,:user_id)
  .group(:actual_user_id,:user_id)
  .having("count(*) > 1")
  .size
```

Comment: I want to know how many duplicates there are, within that time frame which I am trying to specify with the created _at.